# Indirect Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am wondering how I get the data from workbook 1 to workbook2 using the indirect function.

I have this formula currently, but it doesn't work - I am trying to rectify this, someone else built the spreadsheet.

```
=INDIRECT("'[Workbook1.xlsm]"&$A$1&"'!A"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4))
```

This is for a cell reference that is subject to change:

```
&$A$1&
```

Links to the workbook are below.

Workbook(1): https://ibb.co/gfFASn 
Workbook(2): https://ibb.co/h4DfSn
I accept that I am probably incorrect with my code.

The difference is useful answers where given for the clearer explanation I have made to my problem with this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indirect function not working-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49081120/indirect-function-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an extra `A` in your cell reference which follows your sheet name - try this instead:

```
=INDIRECT("'[Workbook1.xlsm]" & $A$1 & "'!" & ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4))
```

Comment: Thanks Lee, very useful, it is now pulling the data across.

When I put an integer in the column section of the address:

        Address(Row(),Column(X),4)

It doesn't seem to work. Do you know what may cause this?

Comment: @Infernez The `reference` argument for the `Column` function should be a cell reference or range of cells for which to return the column (e.g. `=COLUMN(C4)` returns `3` since the cell `C4` appears in the third column of the worksheet). When called without a reference, `COLUMN()` will return the column number of the current cell. Therefore, to specify a fixed column in the formula, simply replace `COLUMN()` with your number (i.e. `ADDRESS(ROW(),3,4)`)